# React Native: Change style prop of 3rd party component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styles

I am building an app using React Native and am trying to alter the styling of a 3rd party component.

It is a List component from `React-Native-Elements` https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/lists.html

The docs state that the  component has a prop of 'containerStyle' with a variety of styling.

How do I overwrite this prop?

I am attempting to change the marginTop prop to 0 (currently set to 20, as per the docs).

```
    return (
     <List style={styles.containerStyle}>
       {
         list.map((item, i) => (
           <ListItem
             key={i}
             title={item.title}
             leftIcon={{ name: item.icon }}
           />
         ))
       }
     </List>
   );
   };

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     containerStyle: {
       marginTop: 0
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List component has a property with the name **containerStyle**, while you are passing a **style** property.

The correct way to use it to pass:

```
containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
```